# Use Javscript libraries in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, require

Im quite new to typescript, so I´m sorry if the question is pretty easy. I want to use JS libraries in a *.ts* file. Also, I´m using node.js to run my program in my console.

In Javascript I used the following line of code:

```
const  example = require('lodash'); // example
```

After that, I typed the following command in my terminal:

```
npm i loadsh
```

Now I have an *example.ts* file, where I want to use the exact same library. Could anyone provide me with an example, of how to do that ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You will need a TSConfig file, https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig

You can create one with `npx tsc --init`

If you want to run the code without building it consider using `ts-node` instead of `node`

You can then do your imports in a tsx file with `import {map} from lodash;`

Be sure to have `"allowJs": true` in your tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article - https://medium.com/@steveruiz/using-a-javascript-library-without-type-declarations-in-a-typescript-project-3643490015f3

Please before asking a question, do a bit of search yourself

Answer (score 0):

Most of npm libraries, including lodash, have typescript definitions provided by developers team. Types for javascript libraries come as separate package, so you need to install it too.

```sh
npm i -D @types/lodash
```